# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

Tags: php

Помогите найти ошибку, уже все перепроверил 20 раз

Выдает 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in D:\wordpress\openserver\OpenServer\domains\php-framework-master\application\models\Main.php on line 35

Вот код с 31-35 строки

```
    public function postsList($route) {
    $max = 10;
    $params = [
        'max' => $max,
        'start' => ((($route['page'] ?? 1) - 1) * $max),
    ];
    return $this->db->row('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 
:start, :max', $params);
  }
```

после вышло Notice, указывает на строку

```
'list' => $this->model->postsList($this->route['page']),
```

весь код

```
public function indexAction() {
    $pagination = new Pagination($this->route, $this->model->postsCount());
    $vars = [
        'pagination' => $pagination->get(),
        'list' => $this->model->postsList($this->route['page']),
    ];
    $this->view->render('Главная страница', $vars);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`??` есть только в новом PHP. Может быть проблема в этом. Можно заменить на `?:`

Comment: пробовал уже, в замен выпадает ошибка 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in D:\wordpress\openserver\OpenServer\domains\php-framework-master\application\models\Main.php on line 35

Comment: @АлексейСоколов а какой у вас php? Я пробовал оба варианта, линтеры показывают, что они валидны

Comment: версия - php 5.4

Comment: @АлексейСоколов я проверил, на 5.4 `'start' => ((($route['page'] ?: 1) - 1) * $max),` работает

Comment: вроде помогло, но вылезла ошибка на след код, можешь тут пожалуйста посмотреть что не так, добавил выше в вопрос

Comment: @АлексейСоколов `$this->route['page']` наверное нужно заменить на `isset($this->route['page']) ? $this->route['page'] : 1` , но лучше знать текст Notice

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: page in D:\wordpress\openserver\OpenServer\domains\php-framework-master\application\controllers\MainController.php on line 15

Comment: да, ошибку убрало вроде с главной страницы, но когда захожу в админку, снова указывает на ошибку первую ---->

Notice: Undefined index: page in D:\wordpress\openserver\OpenServer\domains\php-framework-master\application\models\Main.php on line 35

Comment: @АлексейСоколов `'start' => (((isset($route['page']) ? $route['page'] : 1) - 1) * $max),`

Comment: а стой, секунду попробую

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78074/discussion-between-neo-new-and--).

Comment: все отлично)) работает) можно консультацию еще небольшую ? Сделал админ панель, и запускаю все через опенсервер, сделал способ добавления, редактирования и удаления статей, по урокам где учился там на хостинге сразу запускали и все работало, у меня на локальном не работает, это в этом причина ? если залью на хостинг все будет работать ?

Comment: можешь в вк написать ? https://vk.com/im?peers=346190194&sel=393803404

Comment: репутации не хватает, чтобы там общаться